# How do I resolve a "The policy has been modified by another process" error in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to export the contents of a MySQL table from Google Cloud SQL into a Cloud Storage bucket, and I'm running into an error:

> The policy has been modified by another process. Please try again.

Yesterday, I happily imported CSV data to my Cloud SQL database left and right, and when I tried to write some of the modified data from a query out to another CSV file, I got tripped up. So I followed the directions here to try to resolve my issue: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting?_ga=2.11596404.-1979747439.1580744022

I hit a wall at the end of the day and decided to come back to it later. This morning, I created a new table in my DB and inserted the data into it that I need to export via a query. When I went to export it using the export function in the Cloud SQL console, I get the error message above.

I'm pretty sure I messed something up with permissions somewhere when I was poking around yesterday, but I can't figure out what I did. I'm also having problems with import now, too -- I get a little "Permissions updated" popup, and then this error:

> Operation failed: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Learn more

I'd appreciate any insight into how to undo whatever I apparently did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I opened up another project/storage instance and made sure things matched. For future reference, the permissions for the service account on the storage bucket need to be:

Storage Legacy Bucket Reader
Storage Object Admin
Storage Object Viewer